# Interpreting doubling of metric

Tags: general-relativity, speed-of-light, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, faster-than-light

Say you had coordinates $(x,y,z,t)$ and a beam of light traveling at speed=1.

Now you make a change of coordinates $x'=\frac{1}{2}x, y'=\frac{1}{2}y, z'=\frac{1}{2}z, t'=t$

So now you have a metric tensor $g=diag(-\frac{1}{4},-\frac{1}{4},-\frac{1}{4},1)$.

But according to the new coordinates $(x',y',z',t')$ the beam is traveling at speed=2.

If we expand the metric tensor around flat space $g_{\mu\nu}(x)=\eta_{\mu\nu}(x) + h_{\mu\nu}(x)$. The $h$ represents the gravitational field. Which in this case is non-zero.

Therefor should we interpret this as a beam of light at speed=1 in flat space is equivalent to a beam of light traveling at speed=2 in space with gravitational field $h$?

This interpretation is clearly wrong as we can't have a beam of light travelling at twice the speed of light in a gravitational field $h^{\mu\nu}(x)$. (Or perhaps this interpretation is correct and just means that we never *measure* the speed of light at speed=2 because it's always accompanied by a gravitational field although it's a valid interpretation. But when you quantize gravity on a flat space-time where $h(x)$ become a graviton field, surely this means you would have to include photons travelling faster than the speed of light. Is this a problem? In QFT no signal can go faster than the speed of light - I think - so does this mean quantum gravity is incompatible with QFT?)

Comment: Hint: The metric tensor $\mathbb{g}= g_{\mu\nu}\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}\odot \mathrm{d}x^{\nu}$ is independent of coordinate system, but $g_{\mu\nu}$ transforms under change of coordinates. The speed of light is $c=\frac{1}{|g_{00}|}\sqrt{|g_{ij}\frac{dx^i}{dt}\frac{dx^j}{dt}|}$ if we assume that the metric has no mixed spatio-temporal components $g_{i0}=0$.

Comment: Yes I get that, so the beam of light is at speed=1 on the space-time with background metric g. But if you expand around flat-space and interpret h as a graviton field then the speed=2 on the flat-space background which is somehow compensated for by a background of gravitons which makes it appear like the speed=1.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the coordinates for a second. Then we have a beam of light traveling through a manifold. Draw a line on the manifold representing the path of the light. Then you get a space-time surface with a line drawn on it.

Different coordinate systems represent different ways of drawing grids onto that manifold. Your error lies in assuming that by changing the grid that we draw, we also morph the actual path of the light ray to the new grid. Just because the light ray passes through (0,0), (1,1), (2,2) in one coordinate system does not mean that it will pass through (0,0), (1,1), (2,2) in some other coordinate system. In the other coordinate system, these will probably be completely different space-time points entirely!

In your particular example, take the event $(x=1,y=0,z=0,t=1)$. Then in the primed coordinate system, the same event is $(x^\prime=\frac{1}{2}, y=0, z=0, t=1)$. The metric is different, but the actual numerical values of the coordinates are also different, so there's no paradox.

Comment: You missed my point about interpreting h as a field of gravitons. Then you would have photons travelling at twice the speed of light in a field of gravitons.